# Weird oscilloscope readings with a digital signal (ws2812)

Tags: stm32, oscilloscope

Pretty new to oscilloscopes.  I'm trying to learn stm32, so one of the projects I'm working on is getting ws2812 LEDS working on stm32.  It does work for most strips, however, there are few strips that give me really weird signals on the oscilloscope.

In this first screenshot, I'm probing one of the LED strips that doesn't work.  Notice that even though the signal should be 5V, the signal starts and then immediately drops to below 3V.  I would like to note that this LED strip is known working, and works with an arduino using the Adafruit NeoPixel library.

[image: oscope]

And here's what it looks like hooked up to one of the LED strips that works:

[image: good]

Here's a basic schematic of the setup I'm using (I've got two 100nF caps for the [TXS0101](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txs0101.pdf) and a 10uF capacitor for the 5V supply that aren't shown there).

[image: schematic]

Comment: What is you level shift circuit? How does it look when driven by the arduino? How long is the wire from driver to first ws2812 and which end of it are you probing?

Comment: Is your scope probe properly compensated?

Comment: The level shift circuit is a TSX0101.  The probes are compensated properly.  The signal only looks like that when the LEDs are attached, otherwise it's a more normal looking square wave (which is how it looks with the arduino).  Distance from the MCU to the first LED is about 4 inches, just a jumper wire

Comment: Also, I am probing at the beginning of the strip, before the first LED.

Comment: I've added what it looks like when I use one of the LED strips that works.

Comment: It looks like you are driving too hard. Is there any series resistance or termination on the data line?

Comment: @Oliver: There are two LED strips that don't work (and two that do).  One of the LED strips (that doesn't work) does have a resistor mounted on it right before the first LED (it's an SMD, labeled either 510 or 015).  The other one doesn't have such a resistor, and neither do the two that work.

Comment: @synic: The resistor will be 510, which is 51 ohms. It's a reasonable enough series termination, but it's in the wrong place really. Are you running a long cable from the STM32 to the LED strip? You have ringing and overshoot on both plots, which ought to be fixed (even on the working one). Although I'm sure your data rates are fairly low, the rise time from the STM32 is pretty fast and the drive strength is too high for the transmission line impedance which is likely to be causing the overshoot.

Comment: The data line from the stm32 to the strip is only about 4 inches, but I am just using a breadboard for testing.  So should I try adding a 50ohm resistor on the other end of the strip?

Comment: What voltage is the I/O on the microprocessor?  What voltage does the LED strip need?

Comment: It's indeed very odd that the output voltage appears to get "clamped" - if you modify the software to drive a much longer pulse width (forget about the fact it won't remotely work) what does the waveform look like then?  **And I still want to see what it looks like when driven from the Arduino and working**.

Comment: It turns out that the voltage clamping I'm seeing on the oscilloscope has nothing to do with why the LEDs weren't working.  It was simply a protocol timing issue.  The voltage clamping, etc, is just my setup somehow, and is unrelated.  I'm not sure how to mark this question, it wasn't really answered, but my question has turned out to be invalid anyway.  Any suggestions there?

Comment: Write up your determination (protocol timing) as your own answer.  Or if you want, you can just edit that fact into your question, and revise it to be about the continuing mystery of the "clamping" - but we'll probably want more details on the circuitry.

Comment: Ok, I will make it about the signal flaws, and create a schematic so you can see exactly what's going on.

Comment: The TXS0101 data sheet is a bit opaque, but one thing I notice is that the output high is only .67 Vcc.  There's also some funky time domain behavior likely with those one-shots.  What is most unclear is if the mentioned push-pull vs open-drain options are different varients, or different modes.  I'm not yet convinced that part is an ideal choice.

Comment: Could I use a regular MOSFET like this one? http://www.mccsemi.com/up_pdf/2N7002(SOT-23).PDF

Answer (score 2):

1) Looks like the current draw and/or sourcing capabilities of the output you are looking at is not matching up. Try just connecting a resistor between output pin and ground to get the current you expect and see how that looks on the scope?

2) It also looks like your oscilloscope probe ground lead is too long (too much induction). See if you can use a short ground connection like this:

[image]

That will most likely take care of the "spikes" you see on the scope.

Comment: I'm not really concerned with with the overshooting, rather, with the dip in voltage. The first plot the voltage dips down to ~2.68V right after the rise. I feel like this dip is what is causing some LED strips to not work, as other LED strips don't have this dip and they work fine.

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks.
Looks like the current draw and/or sourcing capabilities of the output you are looking at is not matching up.
Try just connecting a resistor between output pin and ground to get the current you expect and see how that looks on the scope?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a drive issue. There's a reshaping circuit in between LED modules but your MCU board must supply/sink the appropriate amount of current for the ingoing data for the first one. The difference between one strip and another might be a shift around what's specified for typical operation. A few extra microamps might affect your MCU drive capability resulting in a voltage drop. Check those specs for your part.